# Realizar petición Ajax y cargar datos con paginación en Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Estoy intentando traer una consulta de mi base de datos llamando al controlador desde AJAX, luego usar javascript para que me muestre los resultados en un tabla. Pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación el ajax me devuelve esto: {pager:null}

Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Aquí está el código que estoy usando:

**Controlador Usuario.php**

```
public function todosUsuarios(){
        $usuarios = new Usuariosdb();
        
        $usuarios->Tusuarios();
        
        echo json_encode($usuarios);
        
    }
```

**Modelo Usuariosdb.php**

```
 function Tusuarios(){
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $us = $db->query("select us.idusuarios as id, us.nombre , r.nombre as rol, us.estado, us.usuario  from (
                                    select idusuarios, nombre, roles_idroles, estado, usuario from usuarios
                                    ) us, roles  r where r.idroles=us.roles_idroles");
    $us = $us->getResultArray();
  
    return $us;
  }
```

**Routes.php**

```
$routes->get('/todosUsuarios', 'Usuario::todosUsuarios');
```

**usuario.js**

```
function lista_usuarios(){

  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: dir+'/todosUsuarios',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data, 'entro en el success, debería aparecer la consulta');
        $('.hoy #loadcarga').hide();

        if(data.length <1){
          $('.contenedor_usuarios').css({'display':'none'});
          $('.hoy').append("<p class='texto_vacio_u' style='margin: 10px;text-align: center;'>no se ha encontrado ningun resultado.</p>");
        }else{
            $('.contenedor_usuarios').css({'display':'block'});
              $('#tusuarios').DataTable().clear().draw();

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

              $('#tusuarios').DataTable().row.add( [
                '<td class="v-align-middle">'+data[i]['id']+'</td>',
                '<td  class="v-align-middle">'+data[i]['nombre']+'</td>',
                '<td  class="v-align-middle">'+data[i]['usuario']+'</td>',
                '<td class="v-align-middle">'+data[i]['rol']+'</td>',
                '<td ><span class="muted">'+estado(data[i]['estado'])+'</span></td>']).draw();
           }
        }

          eventosclick();
      },
      error: function(data){
          alert("The request failed" + data.responseText);

      }
    });
}
```

**El error que muestra la consola al ejecutar el script**

[image: Error por consola]

```
The request failed
<script>
console.log('[{"id":"1","nombre":"administrador","rol":"master","estado":"1","usuario":"admin"},{"id":"2","nombre":"David Restrepo Parra","rol":"master","estado":"1","usuario":"david.restrepo"},{"id":"3","nombre":"Abilene sanchez","rol":"loterias","estado":"1","usuario":"abilene.sanchez"}
</script>
{"pager":null}
```

Comment: Agrega los mensajes de error por favor

Comment: @DavElsanto listo amigo.

Comment: No agregues imágenes solo copia lo de la consola por favor.

Comment: Verificaste que tu `query` sql trae resultados???

Comment: @DavElsanto Probé la consulta imprimiendo desde el modal y esto me sale:

Comment: The request 
failed<script>console.log('[{"id":"1","nombre":"administrador","rol":"master","estado":"1","usuario":"admin"},{"id":"2","nombre":"David Restrepo Parra","rol":"master","estado":"1","usuario":"david.restrepo"},{"id":"3","nombre":"Abilene sanchez","rol":"loterias","estado":"1","usuario":"abilene.sanchez"}</script>{"pager":null}

Comment: Agrega esa parte por favor

Comment: Segun lo que veo esta entrando por la parte error puedes impimir todo el data . Ejemplo: `error: function(data){console.log(data); }`

Comment: as intentado `$result = []; foreach ($us->getResultArray() as $row) {$result[] =$row;} return $result; ` en `Usuariosdb.php`

Comment: @DavElsanto sí, por esa función es donde me imprime y necesito que lo haga por el sucess.

Comment: @Bryro ya lo intenté y me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: Por eso por favor en la funcion de error que te envie en el comentario anterior ahora va a impirimir por consal agrega que te sale en la consola por favor

Comment: as intentando validar la query desde tu workbench!

Comment: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
: 
ƒ (a)
always
: 
ƒ ()
complete
: 
ƒ ()
done
: 
ƒ ()
error
: 
ƒ ()
fail
: 
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
: 
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
: 
ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType
: 
ƒ (a)
pipe
: 
ƒ ()
progress
: 
ƒ ()
promise
: 
ƒ (a)
readyState
: 
4
responseText
: 
"<script>console.log('[{\"id\":\"1\",\"nombre\":\"administrador\",\"rol\":\"master\",\"estado\":\"1\",\"usuario\":\"admin\"},

Comment: estoy usando xampp y en el phpmyadmin me funciona la consulta

Comment: no entiendo la pregunta o publicacion

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 en resumen estoy haciendo una consulta get desde ajax con php, me trae la consulta que necesito pero me lo imprime en error y necesito que me lo imprima por el sucess.

Comment: si te sale en error eso quiere decir que esta ocurriendo algun error en el request de lado del servidor ... intenta no retornar los datos en su lugar no coloques nada intenda imprimir el response a ver si te sale el mensaje de error...

Comment: lo qu eme dices no es lo que esta en el post

Comment: Gracias, por fin pude solucionar el problema, solo tuve que quitar el return y pone echo json_encode($us) en el modelo y me mostró los datos.